# How to add event handlers in jQuery to code which is rendered after the jQuery itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

EDIT: The Issue has been solved, as it turns out, the Select2 library had a custom command for this typa thing:

```
$("#element").on("change", function (e) { ... }
// Defined as "change"
```

I'm using a dropdown menu library called Select2 3.2. In short, the code takes a bunch of select and option tags, and generates a cool drop down search list.

However, after the site is rendered; when I click 'view source', all my select and option tags are still there, but when I right click the fancy new generated menus themselves and select "inspect element" (using google chrome), the html is TOTALLY different.

I think that this is causing the problem, all this new code is rendered from the custom library's JS, and after my jQuery event commands.

Specifically, here is my command:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.select2-result-label', function() {
        var name = $(this).text();
        var post_to = '/myurl/';
        $.post(post_to, { dat: dat},
            function(response) {
                ...
            }, 'json'
        )
```

I believe the on() method takes care of this kinda stuff but apparently not, any help would be appreciated!

RELEVANT EDIT:
Here is a blurb from another Stack Overflow post:

```
The view page source page shows you the exact text that 
was returned by the server.     

Inspect element actually shows you the fully rendered DOM tree.
```

Knowing that, maybe solving this will be easier.

Here is a JS Fiddle related:

http://jsfiddle.net/JpvDt/47/

Try to make the alert "worked" appear when you click on an "x" in the multi bar.
Right now my code has it to register the class which contains the x's.

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".select2-search-choice-close", alert("worked"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the Select2 library had a custom command for future changes to the toolbar.
Read more here:  http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#programmatic

It's vital to note that many standardized jQuery calls won't work with Select2, you must use their custom set-up.

```
$("#element").on("change", function (e) { ... }
// Defined as "change"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1:**

Your problem is may be you bind **on method** for **whole DOM** which is **really BAD**. So always try to bind that to the **closest div** (closest parent element) which your controls are exist.

About Event performance from **Jquery API says** like below.

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document
>   tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must
>   compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every
>   element in the path from the event target up to the top of the
>   document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document
>   location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive
>   use of document or document.body for delegated events on large
>   documents.

**Scenario 2:**

Call your on event like below (with off event).

```
$(#yourElement).off('click').on('click', '.select2-result-label', function() {
        var name = $(this).text();
        var post_to = '/myurl/';
        $.post(post_to, { dat: dat},
            function(response) {
                ...
            }, 'json'
        )
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: I tried your solution #2 with ${document.body).off('click').on(....) and it did not work unfortunately. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang why don't you give on event for the closest parent the way which I mentioned scenario 1.

Comment: I'll implement that, but how will that affect anything, i'm not looking for any efficiency boost, I just want it to work for now.

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang Actually not only for efficiency may be your problem also will vanish.Just try as a test.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace $(document.body) by $(document)

Comment: Thx for responding, but all of the code is contained in body, so this wont solve it.

Comment: could you make a fiddle with your code. It's a very common issue and that's why jQuery deprecated live method and introduced 'on' with event delegation. It'd be nice to see a fiddle so that we can better participate

Comment: Oh sorry, i got your question wrong. Actually Select2 creates a custom component hiding the conventional select dropdown list. So the event listeners for Select2 component will be different and native binding with 'on' might not work since it will listen to the originally created HTML Dropdown component not the select2 component. In angularJS, we call $scope.apply() which re-initializes the DOM. If you create your fiddle, may be we can play there.